# Bluetooth mouse lagging

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth

I've just bought a new bluetooth mouse (Thinkpad bluetooth mouse). I'm able to connect it and it works but it lags and jumps (the cursor doesn't move smoothly as it should). At first I thought it was a hardware issue (batteries), but I tried it on Windows (running dualboot) and on Widndows it worked without any lags. The mouse is close to the laptop (5-15cm). My laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E531. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. Do anybody know where should the problem be? Thanks forward.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the warning. I will buy a wired mouse instead.

Comment: Interesting, I have a Logitech Ultrathin Touch Mouse (attached to my DELL XPS 13 Ubuntu Edition notebook), which worked just fine with Ubuntu 14.04. Now, after upgrading to 16.04 I have the bluetooth mouse cursor lagging too. I'm not sure, but I think the first few seconds after connecting / pairing the mouse it behaves fine, then it suddenly jumps into the "I feel like I'm on drugs" mode, continuing to move after you stop moving the mouse with your hand.

Comment: Could be a firmware issue (not loading successfully). I've found some help in [fixing a firmware issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323373) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/767046/bluetooth-broadcom-bcm20702-does-not-load-firmware-driver-issue-14-04, also described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working/632348#632348. Though `dmesg` still claims loading the driver has failed the mouse somewhat works now. - If you have installed Blueman try uninstalling it. Some users claimed that to fix their issues.